# How do I loop through an nested dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

if I have a dictionary like this:

```
var dict: [String: Any] = [:]
dict["krusty"] = [
  "job" : "clown",
  "age" : 40
]
dict["homer"] = [
  "job" : "safety inspector",
  "age" : 52
]
```

and I want to loop through this dictionary and get everyone's name, job, and age

```
for item in dict {
  print("k: \(item.key), val: \(item.value)")
}
```

I can loop through the first level like this, but how do I loop through the "item.value"
to look for each entries?

I want to do something like this,

```
for item in dict {
  for val in item {
    //print job and age
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of Any, use a custom type such as Employee (with all the needed properties) to avoid those nested dictionaries. Probably better to use an array if iterating over the entire collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `as?` (until some swift pro answers with the proper way to do it?):

```
import Foundation

var dict: [String: Any] = [:]
dict["krusty"] = [
  "job": "clown",
  "age": 40,
]
dict["homer"] = [
  "job": "safety inspector",
  "age": 52,
]
for item in dict {
  print("Name: \(item.key)")
  if let personDict = item.value as? [String: Any],
    let job = personDict["job"] as? String,
    let age = personDict["age"] as? Int
  {
    print("Job: \(job), Age: \(age)")
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name: homer
Job: safety inspector, Age: 52
Name: krusty
Job: clown, Age: 40
```

***Note:** The reason `homer` is printed before `krusty` is because the order in which the items in a Swift dictionary are iterated over is not guaranteed to be in the same order as they were inserted into the dictionary.*

Answer (score 2):

You could cast this and you could cast that, repeatedly, but you'll be better off just using the type system.

```swift
import Foundation

struct Simperson: Codable {
  let name: String
  let job: String
  let age: Int
}

let simpersons = try JSONDecoder().decode(
  [Simperson].self,
  from: try JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: dict.compactMap {
      guard var dictionary = $0.value as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
      dictionary["name"] = $0.key
      return dictionary
    } as [[String: Any]]
  )
)
```